Can you wear the chain/cassette by always riding in the same gear?
My mate bought an eBike 6 months ago. He's done 600 miles and the chain has started slipping. The bike shop says he's worn the chain and cassette by not using his gears 'properly" and sitting in one gear all the time. But the assistance tops out at 25 kph so of course you are always in 1 of 2 gears? It sounds like rubbish to me but apparently the bike shop are insisting it's his fault.

What sort of motor? A mid drive will stress the chain and cassette more than a hub motor.

Did he ever clean the chain?  Lubricate it?  How dirty is it?   Could also be a budget chain - I've had one "wear out" in 200 km and another last 4000 km.

@Criggie on my electric bike - see my answer, I got 1800km from a (drip) waxed XT chain. So if it’s a similar drivetrain, the value of 600 miles doesn’t surprise me.

Consider changing the chainring to a larger size: 42, 44 or 46T to encourage a wider use of the cassette. Larger rings also wear the chain more slowly due to the higher chain speed and better contact area.

My guess is yes, that is possible.
I'm not familiar with e-bikes, but 1000km in 1-2 cogs sounds similar to 4000km in 4-8 cogs which isn't unreasonably low mileage for a cassette used on a regular bike in a more regular fashion. Add a bit of poor maintenance and/or dirty conditions or perhaps a motor that puts down large torques going uphill at full speed and it doesn't sound impossible at all to me.
But this is just guesswork; perhaps someone else has real experience.

Using only one gear suggests he's using a high assistance level and pulling away from a standing start in a high gear. That will wear the (small) sprocket fast, and therefore the chain.
Maybe he could be tempted to use more of the gears if they were closer together, and spread out the wear.
It's not completely true because of marketing, but if you were expected to use the same gear all the time and rely on the motor making it easy enough, the manufacturer could save a lot of money by making the bike single speed (and single speed drivetrains last much longer)

I don't think they mean that he is literally just using one gear. Just that, once he had maxed out the assistance (the assistance cuts out at 25kph) he's just spinning whichever gear feels most comfortable at that speed. So, on a 25k commute, he might be doing 20k on one particular gear.

@JamesBassett that's possible, but having seen how a lot of people ride (proper legal pedal assist) ebikes, it's very possible he's also pulling away in top. My ex had one and on maximum assistance that was very easy to do

Most of the ebikes I see advertised have fewer gears than comparable non-e-bikes, so they're already heading that way.

@PastychomperthanksMonica I agree, though there's perhaps a little bias in both our views. There are still plenty of cheap bikes (and not just BSOs) with something like 1x7 gearing. Also folding bikes (I've just bought one with hub gears), and I think their target market is quite close to that of many ebikes - non-enthusiasts using them to get about

I recently bought a 7-speed e-bike which is my first e-bike. Before buying I thought 7-speed was low-end/cheap, but actually it's fine with the motor. Lowest gear gets me up steep hills easily even with a lot of luggage (haven't tried with a trailer yet), the steps between gears are large but with the motor it doesn't matter much, and the biggest gear is reasonable up to 35km/h or so. Regarding the actual topic I agree that too many people on e-bikes don't use their gears, it's ridiculuous how often I overtake 1000W bikes when pulling away without having a motor myself.

@Nobody My ex's was a very heavy frame and we put a baby seat on it; babies come with plenty of luggage.  It worked well, and that had 7 gears. But 7-speed is surprisingly OK even without a motor, judging by the old Dahon I just bought. I need to try it on some steep stuff first, but I might change the sprocket to go a tiny bit higher, never needing the lowest gear on my routine commute

The amount of torque and hence chain wear depends on the type of motor. If it is a wheel hub motor in the back it won't add chain stress. If it is a bottom bracket motor (is that what you call it?) then it does work on the chain, and it is important to use the gears to help the motor.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica indeed. I asked the OP under  the question and didn't get an answer, so concentrated on the rider's power. Mid drive (at the BB) is becoming quite common; this appears to be a downside of that arrangement

Yes, it’s possible. I had that with my former e-bike, it was the worst case in terms of torque applied to the smallest sprockets: a mid-drive e-bike with a 10T small sprocket (Shimano 12 speed). The bike was used as commuter in a city, but also in the countryside (dusty or muddy here) for longer day trips.
Because the chainring was only a 36T one, and that cadences are typically slower with e-bikes, I ended up using the smallest sprockets much more than on a conventional bike, first to reach the cut out, and beyond the cut out, I needed to stay in the smallest sprockets to sustain the higher speeds. So I was indeed experiencing the first chain slips on the smallest sprockets after about 1200km - I was aware of the issue, so tried to pedal at higher cadence to limit the use of of the smaller sprockets.
To avoid replacing the whole cassette every time, I replaced the 4 smallest sprockets when I was changing the chain (that lasted about 1800km before reaching the 0.75 mark).
It didn’t make sense economically to replace the Deore drivetrain by a Linkglide one, because it required to change the hub to have a standard HG freehub body, I could find the sprockets separately and I was doing it myself. But if your friend’s bike allows it, it might be worth considering. (Linkglide is a new range from Shimano supposed to be developed for ebikes, and with thicker sprockets, it’s hard to find long term reviews though, to confirm Shimano claims).

Not surprising at all if he rode in the two smallest sprockets all the time. They have the least amount of material and the greatest inefficiencies.
Below you can see a screenshot of my gear usage rate on a road bike (without motor). You can see that I spend 1% (or less) of the time in each of the 4 smallest sprockets. With this kind of usage pattern I expect my cassette to easily last 10 000km. The reason why I use the smaller sprocket so rarely is that I only need them for speeds above ~47km/h, which I pretty much only reach on descents.
Now why is your friend’s usage pattern so much different? They probably have a much smaller chainring (and only one), ride at a lower cadence and spend much more time in the same gear (thanks to the motor which allows you to go 25km/h almost all the time).
The solution: Get the biggest chainring you can mount on the bike (assuming you don’t need easy gear ratios for going uphill). Use the bigger sprockets more, especially when you are accelerating from a standstill or going uphill (your knees will thank you as well!). Try to ride at a higher cadence in the bigger sprockets.
Be aware that the smallest sprockets can usually be replaced independently of the rest of the cassette and cost like 3€, so it’s not a big deal to replace them a bit more often.

I highly recommend playing around with this gear calculator:
https://www.ritzelrechner.de/?GR=DERS&KB=32&RZ=11,13,15,17,19,21,24,28,32,36&UF=2215&TF=90&SL=2.6&UN=KMH&DV=speed (the selected configuration is probably similar to what your friend has and nicely shows why they need the 3 smallest sprockets to go 25km/h or faster at a 90rpm cadence)

A 90rpm cadence is not something you want to do on a ebike used for utility purposes, you should rather aim for a 60rpm cadence.

@Rеnаud Why not? I often do 90rpm on my utility e-bike. Usually when I'm riding faster than the cutoff.

@Nobody An ebike can be used lazily or sportively, usually people who have one is to have the possibility of riding lazily (myself included, no criticism intended), because one of the reason to have an ebike is to arrive "sweat-free" when you go somewhere, which means low cadence, low effort (for me, but judging how e-bike riders can be spotted at the cadence, I'm not alone). So I would not chose my gearing using a 90rpm reference, but a 60rpm one. I was also hitting over 90rpm with mine, but it was when I typically where I didn't care about sweating (on the way back or during the week-end).

Good point @Rеnаud, just spinning fast even without much effort does seem to work up a sweat, like carrying speed from a descent as I did this morning.  Though calculating from my gear ratios and speed, "spinning fast" on this morning's commute means 140rpm - which is about my limit and felt like it, but is interesting on a folder with 20" wheels

Maybe I'm just a weirdo, but I have always considered 60rpm to be a pretty rapid cadence and kind of at the top end for cruising on flat or downhill stretches.  Uphill I can go a lot slower, and I like to push higher gears because it seems to be less effort for the same speed as long as I can maintain that speed on an incline. (Just using leg power, so I can't speak for e-bikes)

@Michael: As far as I’m aware 90rpm is considered the “typical” cycling cadence. Just like 180steps/minute is the standard for running. My average cadence for a medium intensity 2h ride is 95rpm. 60rpm is super slow, are you maybe somehow dividing by two?

@Michael Well like I said, maybe I'm just a weirdo.  I'm basing it on how long it takes to make a single rotation, 60rpm is one complete rotation every second.

@Michael Just an an additional data point, I find it interesting that I am always passing other riders who are pedaling fast than me.  My brain always thinks, "Why don't you gear up and then you could go faster like me..."

@Michael ((do you guys have to have the same user name?)) I also cycle at way lower than 90 rpm at times, and it is more efficient when cruising at low power. Not at high power though, and then low cadence has the disadvantage that it puts much higher loads on the knees while simultaneously providing less movement to allow them to lubricate the joints. IOW, low cadence uphill may work for you now but you risk knee damage later in life. I think it's ok for short efforts out of the saddle (to scale e.g. a bridge ramp without downshifting), but I wouldn't make it a habit for bigger climbs.

Not discussing the value of 90rpm for an experienced cyclist going on a sporty ride. But when using an e-bike for utility purposes, it's a different use-case (no cycling specific clothing, sometimes a willingness to not spend more energy than a walk,...), so my point was just that applying the typical sporting cyclist rules is not the most relevant for me. Also, using 60rpm as reference enables the use of 90rpm, while the opposite is not true. FWIW, the cutoff is reached at 64rpm on Cowboy e-bikes (single speed at variable assistance, very common here, considered sporty/fun to ride).

I believe that the biggest factor in non-ebikes is how clean the chain is. That could also be worth looking at for e-bike riders. Basically, I would suggest:

After each ride, wipe the chain with a rag. This gets dirt off the surface.
Lubricate the chain weekly, then wipe off excess.
If able, get an on-bike chain cleaner. Run the chain through the cleaner once every 3 months or so. You ideally want to run a couple of solvent baths. This can be dilute degreaser, or even dilute Dawn soap. Then let dry and lubricate the chain.
Get a drop-in chain checker. They're cheap. Replace the chain early, for 11s chains this means at 0.5% wear. This is important, it may seem wasteful, but a worn chain will definitely increase wear on the chain and cassette, and those are expensive.

If you are in the smallest cog all the time, then this is likely to be a major factor as well. We have to remember that the motor is supplying additional power. The lower the cadence, the higher the torque needed for the same total power. But the higher the torque, the greater the forces on the chain. Also, the more extreme positions (that is biggest cog or smallest cog) are higher friction and higher wear. So it would definitely be better for your friend to learn to shift and use a greater range of gears.

Is it your friend's fault, as the bike shop implied? Partly yes, in that they could have been more knowledgeable about cleaning and better shifting. And also replacing the chain early, before it skips - otherwise you often have to replace the cassette as well. However, was your friend given the chance to learn this stuff? It's likely that they weren't aware of these things. Bikes are surprisingly complex to operate.
The problem here is that you have your shop floor assistant complete the sale and then maybe quickly brief the rider on what they should do. Most people are not that technically oriented, so most of the information is not likely to persist in memory. If you want to view this as a personal failing, you can but you're also missing part of the point - most people are not very technically oriented, and if you are, it takes some time to get there.
If I were your friend, I'd take the chance to learn that the bike store has a point but perhaps not for the reason they think. It may seem like a lot of work, but replacing your chain every 600 miles is expensive - plus you will burn through cassettes and chainrings and that will be even more expensive. It's just the nature of e-bikes. It's actually the nature of bikes in general, it's just that non-ebikes don't have motor assist.

When my father was buying his e-bike, I was with him. The salesperson definitely did instruct him to shift properly and to help the motor by using different gears in different slope grades. They even mention a person whose motor refused to continue due to overheating when using the same gear even in a big climb (we have some >200 m and around ~10º nearby).

Thanks folks. Lots of useful information there. Just as a bit of background we're on the Isle of Man so think lots of steep hills. And he uses it to commute to work and back, 30 mile round trip with probably a few thousand feet of elevation. Since I showed him your comments he's admitted he leaves it in turbo and often pulls away on the smallest gear!!!?? Oh, and the motor is in the crank. Thanks again

He puts it in the smallest cog. On the one hand, experienced cyclists know that this is not a great idea. On the other hand, as I observed above, there's a lot to learn, so it is not surprising he would do this. BTW, I expect hills to add to the chain wear.

Answer carried forward from Leg-Powered bike.
eBikes have the same problem that I have being a big guy. We can apply a large amount of torque sometimes when we choose to use power instead of shifting to accelerate or climb. This can be construed as 'mis-using the gears' by twiggy little bike shop guys who dance around their shifters like ballerinas.
The result of high pedal torque in a high gear is to apply much greater tension to the metal of your chain, and stretch the chain faster than normal. A stretched chain does land unevenly on the sprocket and gears, and yes this can wear out the gear sooner as well.  I'm not making this up, I've been through it, and so have other riders I know. And my shop tech was kind enough to show me both the stretch in my chain and the corresponding 'shark-fin' appearance in my gear teeth.
If your mate would downshift to lower gears for acceleration or hills, rather than relying on the extra torque to muscle through higher gears... that change would lengthen the life of both his chain and his gears.
But also, why do the bike shop guys feel the need to assign blame? Their job is to fix and advise, not to dish out criticism.

I read the blame as "you have to pay for it because it's not our fault"...

The so-called "stretching" is not a result of literally tensioning the metal plates by a force. The force does play a role, but the "stretching"  is actually the wear of the rolls of the chain. The larger force increases the friction in the rolls and thus the wear. You being a big guy still do not have nearly enough force to stretch the metal, nor have truly super-powerful riders like Chris Hoy. They can sometimes break the chain in the joint but they do not stretch the metal plates in a noticeable way. The steel deformation is pretty elastic anyway.
